# How to copy column but repeat cell content in new column

Tags: google-sheets

I stumped on how to copy a column with unique cell contents into another column but with repeated N entries of each row with Google Sheets.

In sheet 1:

```
A1:A

A2:AA

A3:AAC

A4:AACQ

A5:AAIC

A6:AAL

A7:AAN

A8:AAON

A9:AAP

A10:AAPL

A11:AAU

A12:AAWW

A13:ABB
```

This is what I did in sheet 2:

```
A1:=sheet1!A1 result is A (desired result)

A2:=sheet1!A1 result is A (desired result)

A3:=sheet1!A1 result is A (desired result)

A4:=sheet1!A2 result is AA (desired result)

A5:=sheet1!A2 result is AA (desired result)

A6:=sheet1!A2 result is AA (desired result)
```

I then highlight cells A1:A6 and drag down but my result is:

```
A1:A

A2:A

A3:A

A4:AA

A5:AA

A6:AA

A7:AAN =sheet1!A8 (want this to be =sheet1!A3)

A8:AAN =sheet1!A8 (want this to be =sheet1!A3)

A9:AAN =sheet1!A8 (want this to be =sheet1!A3)

A10:AAON =sheet1!A9 (want this to be =sheet1!A4)

A11:AAON =sheet1!A9 (want this to be =sheet1!A4)

A12:AAON =sheet1!A9 (want this to be =sheet1!A4)

A13:ABB =sheet1A14 (want this to be =sheet1!A5)

A14:ABB =sheet1!A14 (want this to be =sheet1!A5)

A15:ABB =sheet1!A14 (want this to be =sheet1!A5)
```

Is there a way to get my desired result without scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than dragging, one formula can handle this:

`=ArrayFormula(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FILTER(REPT(Sheet1!A:A&"|",3),Sheet1!A:A<>""),"|",1)))`

This will form a virtual array of a triplicate of everything in Sheet1!A:A, each separated by the pipe symbol (|), only for occupied rows. Then `SPLIT` will separate them at that pipe symbol, and `FLATTEN` will make one column of it all.

Comment: Hi Erik, your suggested formula worked perfectly. Thank you for providing guidance and introducing me to SPLIT and FLATTEN! Much appreciated. Have a great day!

Comment: You're welcome, James. Always happy to pass along long-term knowledge with immediate help.